# Not able to update variable in Pyspark

Tags: python, scope, pyspark

I am trying to update a variable in **pyspark** and want to use the same in another method. I am using **@property** in class, when i tested it in python it is working as expected but when i am trying to implement it in **pyspark** it is not updating the variable. Please help me find out what i am doing wrong.

**Code:**

```
class Hrk(object):
    def __init__(self, hrkval):
        self.hrkval = hrkval

    @property
    def hrkval(self):
        return self._hrkval

    @hrkval.setter
    def hrkval(self, value):
        self._hrkval = value

    @hrkval.deleter
    def hrkval(self):
        del self._hrkval


filenme = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/root/CCDs")

hrk = Hrk("No Value")

def add_demo(filename):
   pfname[]
   plname[]
   PDOB[]
   gender[]
   .......i have not mentioned my logic, i skipped that part......
   hrk.hrkval = pfname[0]+"@#"+plname[0]+PDOB[0]+gender[0]
   return (str(hrk.hrkval))


def add_med(filename):
   return (str(hrk.hrkval))


filenme.map(getname).map(add_demo).saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/Demo/")
filenme.map(getname).map(add_med).saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/Med/")
```

In my first method call (add_demo) i am getting the proper value but when i want to use the same variable in the second method i am getting **No Value**  . I don't know why it is not updating the variable. Where as similar logic working fine in python.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mutate the state of a global variable using the `map` API. This is not a recommended pattern for Spark. You try to use pure functions as much as possible, and use [operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.html#pyspark.RDD) like `.reduce` or `.reduceByKey` or `.foldLeft`. The reason the following simplified example does not work is because when `.map` is called, spark creates a closure for the function `f1`, creates a copy of `hrk` object for each "partition" and applies this to the rows within each partition.

```py
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql

number_cores = 2
memory_gb = 1
conf = (
    pyspark.SparkConf()
        .setMaster('local[{}]'.format(number_cores))
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '{}g'.format(memory_gb))
)

c = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

class Hrk(object):
    def __init__(self, hrkval):
        self.hrkval = hrkval

    @property
    def hrkval(self):
        return self._hrkval

    @hrkval.setter
    def hrkval(self, value):
        self._hrkval = value

    @hrkval.deleter
    def hrkval(self):
        del self._hrkval

hrk = Hrk("No Value")
print(hrk.hrkval)
# No Value

def f1(x):
    hrk.hrkval = str(x)
    return "str:"+str(hrk.hrkval)


data = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
data.map(f1).collect()
# ['str:1', 'str:2', 'str:3']

print(hrk.hrkval)
# No Value
```

You can read more about closures in [Understanding Closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-) section in the rdd programming guide on official spark docs, here are some important snippets:

> One of the harder things about Spark is understanding the scope and life cycle of variables and methods when executing code across a cluster. RDD operations that modify variables outside of their scope can be a frequent source of confusion. In the example below we’ll look at code that uses foreach() to increment a counter, but similar issues can occur for other operations as well.

> In general, closures - constructs like loops or locally defined methods, should not be used to mutate some global state. Spark does not define or guarantee the behavior of mutations to objects referenced from outside of closures. Some code that does this may work in local mode, but that’s just by accident and such code will not behave as expected in distributed mode. Use an Accumulator instead if some global aggregation is needed.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-